# Store list of dictionaries as a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Suppose I have List of dictionaries as

```
 l = [{'car':'good'},
      {'mileage':'high'},
      {'interior':'stylish'},
      {'car':'bad'},
      {'engine':'powerful'},
      {'safety':'low'}]
```

Basically these are noun-adjective pairs.

1. How can I visualize whats the most associated list of adjective to
   lets say car here.
2. How to convert this to Data frame? , I have tried `pd.Dataframe(l)`
   , but here the key is not the column name so gets little bit tricky
   here.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: So you want to have a row for every item in the list, or a a column for every item?

Comment: i want column for noun and column for corresponding adjective

Comment: How do you want the output look a like?

Comment: Basically noun = ['car','mileage','interior','car','engine','safety'] and adj = ['good','high','stylish','bad','powerful','low'] ....These are two columns and then convert this to dataframe

Comment: @gftsp - Please edit your question to include a sample output so that we can help you better.

Comment: For the first part of your question, you could use groupby when you have the dataframe: `counts = df.groupby(['Noun']).size().reset_index(name='Count')` and then
`counts[counts['Count'] == counts['Count'].max()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want this to be done column-wise, then you have to re-structure your list of dictionaries. You need to have one dictionary to represent one row. Therefore, your example list should be (I added a second row for better explainability):

```
 l = [
     {'car':'good','mileage':'high','interior':'stylish','car':'bad','engine':'powerful','safety':'low'}, # row 1
     {'car':'bad','mileage':'low','interior':'old','car':'bad','engine':'powerful','safety':'low'} # row 2
 ]
```

At this point, all you have to do is call `pd.DataFrame(l)`.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, I think you need to convert the dictionary to a list to get your desired result. Here is a quick way (I'm sure it can be much more efficient):

```
l = [{'car':'good'},
      {'mileage':'high'},
      {'interior':'stylish'},
      {'car':'bad'},
      {'engine':'powerful'},
      {'safety':'low'}]

new_list = []
for item in l:
    for key, value in item.items():
        temp = [key,value]
        new_list.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(new_list, columns=['Noun', 'Adjective'])
```

Comment: No you didnt get me.........what i need is key element of every dictionary to be in noun column and value element of every dictionary to be in adjective column in a  dataframe....I have list  which have 20,000 such noun adjcetive pairs

Comment: @gftsp I edited my answer, have a look. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Glad that I helped you, @gftsp! If you could mark my answer as accepted, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your DataFrame by giving a list of tuples. To get tuples from a dict use the method items(). Construct the list of tuples with a list comprehension by taking the first tuple of each items.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[d.items()[0] for d in l],columns=['A','B'])
print df
```

Gives :

```
          A         B
0       car      good
1   mileage      high
2  interior   stylish
3       car       bad
4    engine  powerful
5    safety       low
```